# Boost.format and wide characters

Tags: c++, unicode, boost, format

Is there a way to get boost.format to use and return wide (Unicode) character strings?

I'd like to be able to do things like:

```
wcout << boost::format(L"...") % ...
```

and

```
wstring s = boost::str(boost::format(L"...") % ...)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`format_fwd.hpp` contains this typedef:

```
typedef basic_format<wchar_t >  wformat;
```

I think this will get you started. This works here:

```
std::wcout << boost::wformat(L"...") % ...
```

Also the `boost::str` works using `wformat`.

Comment: I'm surprised how easy to use boost::format is. didn't know you can print into a string that way. i certainly have to have a look at it